# django.server logs are not shown in CloudWatch - Using Zappa

Tags: python, django, logging, aws-lambda, zappa

My django application is running on AWS Lambda with zappa. I recently added the following to configure logs.

```
LOGGING = {
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": False,
    "filters": {
        "require_debug_false": {
            "()": "django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse",
        },
        "require_debug_true": {
            "()": "django.utils.log.RequireDebugTrue",
        },
        "filter_user_id": {"()": "<path_to>.UserIdFilter"},
    },
    "formatters": {
        "django.server": {
            "format": "[%(asctime)s] %(message)s user_id:%(user_id)s ",
        }
    },
    "handlers": {
        "console": {
            "level": "INFO",
            "filters": ["require_debug_true"],
            "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
        },
        "django.server": {
            "level": "INFO",
            "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
            "formatter": "django.server",
        },
    },
    "loggers": {
        "django": {
            "handlers": ["console"],
            "level": "INFO",
        },
        "django.server": {
            "handlers": ["django.server"],
            "filters": ["filter_user_id"],
            "level": "INFO",
            "propagate": False,
        },
    },
}
```

This is working well when I run this on docker / local server. But when I deployed this to AWS Lambda it is not showing the corresponding logs in the Cloudwatch.

Could anyone help? Thanks in advance.